# How to adjust font size to fit height (not width) in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

`label.minimumScaleFactor` works very well to fit the font to the width.

However the font size, for alphabet such as "I", is typically larger than other letters such as "H". This makes the design very weird.

I need help to fit the font to the label height. Any solutions/functions/class that I can adopt?

Comment: coded programmically

Comment: try this    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift 3...**

```
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1    //you need
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true    
label.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. The error for mine was numerOfLines = 1